# After url rewrite, the system adds the extension

Tags: .htaccess

With the following rules in my .htaccess, the system adds a `.php` at the end of my url's.

```
RewriteEngine On

# Removing extension
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^app/([^/]+)$ app.php?module=$1 [L]
```

Why ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have your first rule add `.php` only after checking if `.php` file exists:

```
RewriteEngine On

# add extension
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^([^.]+?)/?$ $1.php [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^app/([^/]+)$ app.php?module=$1 [L,QSA,NC]
```